# Which sentence is correct? first one or second one?

Tags: word-usage

- For their viewers, it's not matter which university they graduate from.
- For their viewers, it's not matter which university they were graduated from.

Comment: Neither is correct. The word cluster "it's not matter which" is simply wrong. Use "it doesn't matter which"—after that it doesn't matter which sentence ending you choose.

Comment: For their viewers, ''it doesn't matter which university they graduate from.''            Is this correct?

Comment: Yep, that works. It's also idiomatic. You can also say "It doesn't matter which university they **graduated** from or "It doesn't matter which university they **were graduated** from. The differences are stylistic only.

Comment: OK I didn't know I have to use v2 form of graduate in both way. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Robusto's right, with the proviso that "were graduated from" is(1)  a Britishism and (2) pretty stilted in in Blighty.

Answer (score 0):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary and others we must use only Active Voice.
For example: He graduated from the university last June.
So, in our case, the only sentence which is grammatically correct is:
It doesn't matter which university they graduated from.

Comment: What in the world are you talking about?  First, no dictionary demands that you only use active voice.  Second, even if it did it wouldn't matter; dictionaries aren't the arbiter of correctness.  Third, if it's in common usage and understood, it's correct.  Passive voice is a perfectly valid and legitimate construction to use.

Answer (score 0):

There is same mistake in both the sentences. Either write ' It's no matter' or ' It does not matter'. Passive use of the verb "graduate"  is a  matter of choice; so is the use of tense according to context. Otherwise they are alright.